# Remove all occurrences of an item in ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am trying to remove all occurrences of an item in the arraylist

```
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
list.Add("2.2");
list.Add("2.5");
list.Add("2.6");
list.Add("2.2");
list.Add("2.5");
list.Add("2.2");
```

How can remove all 2.2 values from the list?I have used

```
list.Remove("2.2")
```

but it removes only first occurrence

Comment: I think you have a typo. It's `list.Remove` not `list.remove`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the docs on [ArrayList.Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.remove(v=vs.110).aspx), in particular:

> Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the ArrayList.

Why are you using an `ArrayList` anyway? The elements in your example are all the same type, you would be better off using a `List<string>` and then using [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) e.g.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.add("2.2");
list.add("2.5");
list.add("2.6");
list.add("2.2");
list.add("2.5");
list.add("2.2");

list.RemoveAll(item => item == "2.2");
```

Comment: Why do you answer the question TS didn't ask?

Comment: @ValentinP. When a better solution is available, why *wouldn't* you provide it? Using an `ArrayList` when your elements are all the same type is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I mean the question is about ArrayList, not List<T>. Thus, probably, using of ArrayList makes sense in this certain case. If you are talking about List<T> when questions is about ArrayList, I think at first you should provide solution for ArrayList and only after that tell something about List and why it is better. As for me, I think better solution have been already posted.

Comment: `using of ArrayList makes sense in this certain case.` - except it clearly doesn't since all of the array elements are of the same type. `ArrayList` is deprecated and belongs in a time when C# didn't have generics. With `List<T>` you avoid casting issues, you get the benefits of LINQ, you avoid boxing/unboxing value types not to mention the fact that `ArrayList` consumes [2x as much memory as `List<T>` on 64 bit machines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2004/04/13/112598.aspx), please explain why the OP *should* be using `ArrayList`?

Comment: Thanks for the lecture about ArrayList :). You don't know if TS actually stores only strings in his list (I hope you don't think that depicted code fragemnt is a real production code). Again, firstly answer what actually someone asks, secondly provide some extra-content according to your understanding of the problem. IMHO.

Comment: @ValentinP. Has the OP given any reason to believe that this is an incomplete code sample? Going by your logic how are we supposed to answer any question at all? Afterall, it might not be the actual code he's using right! Flawed reasoning my friend :) and you're welcome, stick around on SO, you might learn something..

Comment: :) I didn't find anything new for me in your comment or answer, but thanks for the invitation. I've told enough, let's stop here.

Comment: @ValentinP. Well since this has been accepted as the answer I think it's fair to assume that this is the correct approach for the OP's scenario... ;)

Comment: ok, you're right with your answer. But if you mentioned the solution with ArrayList, it would be a great answer. And I would have upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

### The new approach

[Generic Collections in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762916(v=vs.110).aspx) are there to replace the outdated `ArrayList` thing, which has certain design and performance issues.

Here is an example of using the [`List<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var list=new List<string>();
list.Add("2.2");
list.Add("2.5");
list.Add("2.2");
// ...

list.RemoveAll(item => item == "2.2");
```

### Problem with legacy code

However, there are some cases when we are bound to use the outdated `ArrayList` class, for example when working with with legacy code.

Even more, sometimes legacy APIs require working with the same instance of ArrayList, and in this case we need a fast and reliable method to work with.

### Filling the gap

Here is an implementation of the RemoveAll extension which fills the gap:

```
public static class ArrayListExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all the elements equal to <paramref name="sample"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">List to remove from.</param>
    /// <param name="sample">Element to remove.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the number of removed elements.</returns>
    public static int RemoveAll(this ArrayList list, object sample)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

        var n = list.Count;
        var nextOut = 0;
        var nextIn = 0;

        for (; nextIn < n && nextIn == nextOut; nextIn++)
        {
            var token = list[nextIn];
            if (!Equals(token, sample))
            {
                nextOut++;
            }
        }

        for (; nextIn < n; nextIn++)
        {
            var token = list[nextIn];
            if (!Equals(token, sample))
            {
                list[nextOut] = token;
                nextOut ++;
            }
        }

        if (nextOut < list.Count)
        {
            var toRemove = list.Count - nextOut;
            list.RemoveRange(nextOut, toRemove);
            return toRemove;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This method makes just the necessary underlying `ArrayList` API calls, works in-place, and has no added complexity beyond what's actually needed, which is O(n).

Comment: +1 for recommending a **real** solution. There is absolutely no reason to be using an `ArrayList` here.

Answer (score 3):

Description of [`ArrayList.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) is clear:

> Removes the **first occurrence of a specific object** from the ArrayList. *(emphasis mine)*

You can do this:

```
while (list.Contains("2.2"))
{
    list.Remove("2.2");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using List is the best choice as described above. But if you insist to use `ArrayList` then you can do something like this.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add("2.2");
list.Add("2.2");
list.Add("2.5");
list.Add("2.6");
list.Add("2.2");
list.Add("2.5");

do{
    list.Remove("2.2"); 
} while (list.Contains("2.2"));
```

may be another way..

```
list.Sort();
int i = list.LastIndexOf("2.2");
int j = list.IndexOf("2.2");
list.RemoveRange(j,i-j+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways:

```
int index;
while ((index = list.IndexOf("2.2")) > -1)
{
    list.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

or:

```
while (list.Contains("2.2"))
{
    list.Remove("2.2");
}
```

or:

```
list = new ArrayList(list.Cast<string>().Where(item => s != "2.2"));
```

Comment: Almost all of them are also very expensive when they don't have to be. For long lists.. they are sure to show the effect of how poor performing these operations are.. be cautious.

Comment: @VikasGupta I agree, but I hope that the OP's realizes that since he is using that structure.

Comment: Absolutely no need to raise algorithmic complexity to O(N^2) here.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is with a lambda function and the RemoveAll:

```
list.RemoveAll(x => x == 2.2)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
ArrayList arryList2 = new ArrayList();
arryList2.Add(100);
arryList2.Add(200);
arryList2.Add(100);

while (arryList2.Contains(100))
arryList2.Remove(100);
```

Comment: Answering questions is good but this just repeats details already given in other answers. Further this answer has no explanations as to why it is useful. This code would be much more useful if there was also an explanation of how this code answers the users question.